# Approve a device without having another Apple device

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, mojave, apple-id

I have a company MacBook Pro, so I am a little bit restricted in administration setting.

By the way, I need to access iCloud, that was created with the previous MacBook Pro (changed some weeks ago) and where there are important documents that I would like to sync with this new one.

The problem is that when I try to sync iCloud it is asking for the Apple ID login, the iCloud login and then to *go to another device signed in to iCloud and approve this device*.

Now, if I log in to iCloud, and also Apple ID, **I can only see this new device registered** in both my accounts, as the old MacBook was previously removed as no more used.

I have already tried to remove this new MacBook to have **no device** registered in any of the accounts (iCloud and Apple ID) and tried again the procedure. Correctly, when logging in, I am receiving the SMS with the code to my phone (not Apple) for the 2FA, but then the procedure tells me every time to go to another device signed in to iCloud and approve the current MacBook. Only at this point, in both the accounts, I can see that this new MacBook has been added again to the devices section.

As you can imagine, I do not have any other Apple device to approve this new MacBook and the solution proposed else where in this website, are not helpful because they suppose you have another Apple device or they just say what I have already tried and wrote above.

Is there anything that I can try about that?

Comment: Have you tried adding your phone number to your iCloud account? Apple can send verification text messages to any phone that will get text messages.

Comment: The Account Setting from iCloud is then calling the Apple ID Account Setting, and, as I already explained in the question, the phone number is already set in the Apple ID as I am correctly receiving the SMS with the verification code to proceed in the procedure that I have already described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an iCloud keychain prompt. In order to allow you to sign in to the Mac, you'll need to approve it. If you only have one device on the account then you must have had another apple device in the past that you used to set up keychain. Often times some users will turn keychain on and then realize they don't know what it is or what it does so they turn it off. The moment its turned on, you activate it and it identifies itself with your Apple ID.

If you don't care about iCloud Keychain, the screen should get you an option to [**reset iCloud Keychain**](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202755). It should say "Can't approve from another device". Once you click on that, next it will say "If you can’t approve this Mac from another device, you can reset your end-to-end encrypted data to finish setting up iCloud". That data is your keychain passwords, wifi passwords, Messages saved in iCloud and credit card numbers (more info below). If you don't care that it will erase that information from your account, then have it reset the keychain and it will allow you to continue to the phone setup.

*iCloud keychain is a secure management feature that keeps your account names, passwords, [Messages in iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208532) and even credit card numbers stored behind 256-bit AES encryption on Apple's iCloud servers. Then that data is synced between authorized iOS/iPadOS devices and macOS devices.*

Comment: As I was illustrating in the question, I had an old MacBook Pro that was taken away from the company and replaced with the new one. So, yes, I had a previous device, but now that device is no more operative. I do not have any option to reset the Keychain and, again, I do not have any other Apple device to do the procedure in the link you pointed out. So, the question now is: how to get rid of this Keychain?

Comment: It doesnt give you an option that says "Can't approve from another device?"

Comment: Yes it does, and that's the problem because it is then asking to "If you can’t approve this Mac from another device, you can reset your end-to-end encrypted data to finish setting up iCloud" but I actually do not want to reset the data as there there are important documents that I need.

Comment: I explained what that data is: keychain passwords and Messages in iCloud. If you don't have any of those that you care to keep then reset it. Otherwise, you cant proceed.

Comment: It seems it has worked, even though this process is really ambiguous: how they suppose someone to know all these things? Bah... Can you improve the answer also with these specification that you gave me in these comments? I will accept it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Sure will. Glad that it helped.

Comment: If you want you can also modify it to your liking. My version can be a bit "wordy"